# How to create parallax effect while scrolling a viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, parallax

I've incuded in my app a viewpager which contains 3 fragements with 3 different layouts. Navigating on the net i found these really nice example, i want to add them to my fragments in order to offer a more intersting expercience to the user.

[Github resource 1](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/ParallaxPager)

[Github resource 2](https://github.com/ryanhoo/Zhihu-Parallax-Animation)

Unfortunely they are both compiled in grandle, but i'm working with eclpise. So, my first question is: is possible to "convert" these project and import them to eclipse? And the second: if not, can you give me a working example or a first point to start?

This is my Activity:

```
public class WelcomeScreen extends FragmentActivity{
    List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
       List<String> fragmentTitles = new Vector<String>();

       private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

       private ViewPager mPager;

       @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.welcomescreen);

        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, welcome1.class.getName()));
        fragmentTitles.add("Step 1");
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, welcome2.class.getName()));
        fragmentTitles.add("Step 2");
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, welcome3.class.getName()));
        fragmentTitles.add("Step 3");

        this.mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter1(super.getSupportFragmentManager(),fragments,fragmentTitles);
        mPager = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.pager);
          View pagerStrip = findViewById(R.id.pagerTabStrip);
          mPager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);

       }
}
```

And this one of the fragments:

```
public class welcome1 extends Fragment {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (container == null) {
             return null;
          }
          // inflate view from layout
          View view = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.welcome1,container,false);
          return view;

    }
```

Thanks to all! :)

Answer (score 0):

Hey~ I'm the author of the second repo you've mentioned above. ;-D

Though I've abandoned eclipse for years. I can definitely assure you that eclipse supports gradle projects as well as intellij-like IDE, such as android studio.

But ah ... given android studio is the officially recommended dev tool, why don't you use it? Or at least use the intellij community edition is much better than the clumsy eclipse.